# Cm Synergy File Renaming Issu

Tags: cm-synergy

I am using cm synergy 7.1.

I have to rename a file from say x to y.
But there is no option(not even in right click menu) in synergy GUI for renaming files.
So I am using CLI.

When I try to move it to a new file it gives me below error:

```
# ccm move x y
Warning: No sessions found.
Please run 'ccm start' to start a session.
```

When I try to start ccm session it gives me error:

```
ccm start -h ccm-srv -d /dbs/db1 -m -q -rc -nogui
Warning: bad rfc address (ccm-srv:8830)
Warning: Engine startup failed.
Warning: IBM Rational Synergy startup failed.
```

When I try to move file using cmsynergy71 command it just opens synergy gui.

```
cmsynergy71 move x y
```

What am I missing and how to rename a file?

Answer (score 0):

To rename a file in synergy GUI first you must checkout the file, then there is an option to rename.

[image]

Not sure about the CLI. Looks like you need to provide it a qualified server address not just your hostname.